# SlickJS carousel - vertical mode cuts off the copy and does not function as expected

Tags: slick.js

I've made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/NeroSonic/pen/QWbMLpZ) showcasing a problem with the *vertical* functionality of the [Slick Carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). As you can see in the CodePen, I have three testimonials of different heights. When you scroll through them, you'll notice that the content gets *cut off* and does not display the copy correctly on screen.

Here's what I do to accomplish a vertical carousel using SlickJS:

```
$('.slick-carousel').slick({
  vertical: true,
  dots: true
})
```

Would there be a setting I'm missing in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a little digging around and I fell upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241256/2924072). I've tried it out on my CodePen above and it seems to be working fine.

If anyone has any better solution, do let me know in this thread!